# Types that own disposable fields should be disposable. how to solve this warning?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

I tried using **Run Code Analysis** option in `VisualStudio 2012`, as a result of it I got a warning as

```
CA1001  Types that own disposable fields should be disposable
Implement IDisposable on 'DBConnectivity' 
because it creates members of the following IDisposable types: 'SqlConnection', 'SqlCommand'.
```

I referred some question in SO, but I couldn't catch the point regarding `IDisposable`
and following is the class, responsible for this warning.

```
class DBConnectivity
    {
        public SqlConnection connection = null;
        public SqlCommand command = null;
        public SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
        public string connectionString = null;
        public List<MasterTableAttributes> masterTableList;
        public DBConnectivity()
        {
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Master"].ConnectionString;
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());

            //-----Master table results 
            connection.Open();
            string masterSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM MASTER_TABLE";
            command = new SqlCommand(masterSelectQuery, connection);
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            masterTableList = new List<MasterTableAttributes>();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                MasterTableAttributes masterTableAttribute = new MasterTableAttributes()
                {
                    fileId = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Id"]),
                    fileName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["FileName"]),
                    frequency = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Frequency"]),
                    scheduledTime = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Scheduled_Time"])
                };
                masterTableList.Add(masterTableAttribute);
            }
            dataReader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

I am really confused in implementing the IDisposable.  Any help appreciated?

Comment: What exactly is your question: how to implement IDisposable or why implementing it? You might want to look at [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/301100-disposing-objects-everything-about-dispose/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fully agree with the compiler - you need to dispose your fields here, or (as already noted) - not make them fields in the first place:

```
class DBConnectivity : IDisposable // caveat! read below first
{
    public void Dispose() {
        if(connection != null) { connection.Dispose(); connection = null; }
        if(command != null) { command.Dispose(); command = null; }
        if(dataReader != null) { dataReader.Dispose(); dataReader = null; }
    }
```

Note that you would then use this type via `using(...)`

---

However! It looks like a static method would be more appropriate:

```
static class DBConnectivity
{
    public static List<MasterTableAttributes> GetMasterTableList()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Master"].ConnectionString;
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            const string masterSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM MASTER_TABLE";
            using(var command = new SqlCommand(masterSelectQuery, connection))
            using(var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var masterTableList = new List<MasterTableAttributes>();

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    MasterTableAttributes masterTableAttribute = new MasterTableAttributes()
                    {
                        fileId = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Id"]),
                        fileName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["FileName"]),
                        frequency = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Frequency"]),
                        scheduledTime = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Scheduled_Time"])
                    };
                    masterTableList.Add(masterTableAttribute);
                }
                return masterTableList;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or perhaps simpler with a tool like "dapper":

```
static class DBConnectivity
{
    public static List<MasterTableAttributes> GetMasterTableList()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Master"].ConnectionString;
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            const string sql = "SELECT Id as [FileId], FileName, Frequency, Scheduled_Time as [ScheduledTime] FROM MASTER_TABLE";
            return connection.Query<MasterTableAttributes>(sql).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I am using these variables in other class, will this affect?

Comment: @user1671639 which variables are you using in another class? the reader that has been consumed? the command that has been executed? it sounds to me like you're simply leaking data incorrectly

Comment: I am using the `connection`, `dataReader`, `command` variables.  But I have properly closed the `dataReader` and `connection`.  Will this tend to data leak?

Comment: @user1671639 but *why* are you using them? they clearly don't hold any useful *objects* (since they have been closed, in theory) - let the caller declare their own variables. Also: not you have **not** properly closed the `dataReader` etc; firstly they should be **disposed** (which they aren't being), and secondly: if anything goes wrong in your current code, you have lost the open connection into the ether; you should use `using` blocks to ensure that the connection, command and reader are all disposed *even if there is an error*. I give examples of this above.

Comment: Thanks.  I have multiple queries in my project, that the reason I am reusing these variables.  Is there a better way?

Comment: @user1671639 that isn't a reason... those variables aren't useful between queries - they are pointing at dead objects. The "better" way is to correctly scope them, basically: like in the two examples above. I would, however abstract the "get a connection" code - either a separate `static` method, or some other layer of abstraction (IoC, factory, provider, take your pick) - a basic `private static DBConnection CreateConnection() {...}` works well for simple cases, though

Comment: I have posted a question releated to above we have discussed.  If possible please have a look.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542403/how-to-handle-multiple-queries-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542403/how-to-handle-multiple-queries-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @user1671639 feedback provided

Answer (score 1):

If that is you complete class you should move all the SQL variables inside the constructor. Or perhaps change the constructor to a static function that return the `masterTableList`

Comment: if that is the complete class, it should just be a static method, not an object

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, that returns `masterTableList`